# Why are timestamps imported via Python's numpy.loadtxt off by 6 to 7 hours?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to import some Twitter text date from a file into a Python array. I wrote the following function:

```
import numpy as np

# Load data from a text file into an array and return the array contents
def load_text_file(file_path, file_name):
 try:
  text_data = np.loadtxt(file_path.strip() + file_name.strip(), dtype={'names': ('UserId', 'CreatedAt', 'CollectedAt', 'NumerOfFollowings', 'NumberOfFollowers', 'NumberOfTweets', 'LengthOfScreenName', 'LengthOfDescriptionInUserProfile'), 'formats': ('i8', 'datetime64[us]', 'datetime64[us]', 'i8', 'i8', 'i8', 'i8', 'i8')}, delimiter="\t")
  return text_data
 except IOError as e:
  print(e)
```

When I look at the timestamp objects imported, they seem to be off by 6 hours in one case and by 7 hours in the other. Here are two sample lines of data that I am trying to import:

```
5945472 2007-05-10 20:12:18 2009-11-17 20:09:52 156 223 2134 10 54
5947912 2007-05-10 22:08:58 2009-11-19 11:28:25  52  37  730  7 32
```

These are being imported into a Python array as follows:

```
(5945472, datetime.datetime(2007, 5, 11, 2, 12, 18), datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 18, 3, 9, 52), 156, 223, 2134, 10, 54)
(5947912, datetime.datetime(2007, 5, 11, 4, 8, 58), datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 19, 18, 28, 25), 52, 37, 730, 7, 32)
```

As you can see, the timestamps are off by 6 and 7 hours. I'm not sure why. As a result of the change, the date gets changed to the next day. Would someone know how I can import the timestamps exactly as they are? Thanks!!!

Comment: Weird, seems like it's incrementing by one each time. Notice: `20` -> `2` (+4), `20` -> `3` (+5), `22` -> `4` (+6), and `11` -> `18` (+7).

Comment: I think it's adding 6 hours to the first time stamp in a row and 7 hours to the second one. It's actually 20- > 2 (+6) not +4. If I change the date 2007-05-10 to 2007-11-10, then the offset becomes +7 instead of +6. I think it's something to do with YMD vs YDM. However, I don't get why it's adding the 7 hours. I live in Utah and it's 7 hours behind GMT. Maybe it's got something to do with that. Not sure how I can specify the offset to be zero hours.

Comment: Oh right, I'm thinking in terms of a 12-hour format. :) I tried this locally and got different results: `datetime.datetime(2007, 5, 11, 0, 12, 18), datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 18, 1, 9, 52)` and `datetime.datetime(2007, 5, 11, 2, 8, 58), datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 19, 16, 28, 25)`. Perhaps it's something to do with timezones? (although I'm not sure why it would change depending upon the column)

Comment: The difference changing could be due to daylight saving. The 2007 date is of the 5th month and 2009 date is of the 11th month. These 2 times should have different daylight saving.

Comment: You say that they are being `imported into a Python array as follows`. How do you know that? Did you print the numbers? If yes, how?

Comment: I just used print on the array returned by load_text_file(). You're right, the daylight savings time could explain the difference between the 6 vs 7 hours difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is the solution you are looking for but, why not import as a string and then create a datetime object of it.

```
def load_text_file(file_path, file_name):
    try:
        text_data = np.loadtxt(file_path.strip() + file_name.strip(), dtype={'names': ('UserId', 'CreatedAt', 'CollectedAt', 'NumerOfFollowings', 'NumberOfFollowers', 'NumberOfTweets', 'LengthOfScreenName', 'LengthOfDescriptionInUserProfile'), 'formats': ('i8', 'a25', 'a25', 'i8', 'i8', 'i8', 'i8', 'i8')}, delimiter="\t")
        text_data2 = convert_date(text_data)
        return text_data2
    except IOError as e:
        print(e)

def convert_date(text_data):
    text_data2 = list()
    for line in text_data:
        new_line = list()
        for item in line:
            if isinstance(item, str):
                new_line.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(item, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
            else:
                new_line.append(item)
        text_data2.append(tuple(new_line))
    return text_data2
```

This returns the following for me:

```
[(5945472, datetime.datetime(2007, 5, 10, 20, 12, 18), datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 17, 20, 9, 52), 156, 223, 2134, 10, 54),
(5947912, datetime.datetime(2007, 5, 10, 22, 8, 58), datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 19, 11, 28, 25), 52, 37, 730, 7, 32)]
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, this is a result of the way numpy creates `datetime` objects from a `datetime64`. Notice:

```
>>> np.datetime64('2009-11-17 20:09:52-0500')
numpy.datetime64('2009-11-17T20:09:52-0500')
>>> np.datetime64('2009-11-17 20:09:52-0500').item()
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 18, 1, 9, 52)
>>> np.datetime64('2009-11-17 20:09:52-0500').item().tzinfo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

In this example, I specifically specified the timezone as UTC-5:00. However, the `datetime` object was created with no offset; thus it displays as the UTC time.

So how can you work around this? You can work solely in `datetime64`'s -- these already have the timezone information correctly specified, and so calculations should work correctly. Or, if you want to work with `datetime`'s, you can add timezone information to them before performing any calculations (i.e. `d.item().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("America/New_York"))`). More than likely, working solely with `datetime64`'s would be the easier route.